# Unable to take screenshot in Kivy app running on android

Tags: android, kivy

I have an android app made with Kivy(based on the Simple Paint App tutorial)and it is working fine on the desktop. But when I create the APK and launch it on my phone, it crashes when I press the save button. As you can see in my code(http://pastebin.com/RJErexHa) I am using Window.screenshot() to save the PNG. I think the problem is the app can not find where to save the PNG. On the desktop(Ubuntu) the screenshot is saved it the directory with main.py.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the instructions [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform) to see the traceback. If you don't understand it, paste it here.

It's possible you're hitting a bug that was in kivy master for a while, and may still be in the stable version used by the build tools. The traceback would confirm this if it's a particular ImportError. Other things are also possible, which is why the traceback is important.

It's probably not a problem with saving locally, the app has write permissions in its own directory, though I suppose it's not impossible something else could come up.

Comment: Im getting "Unknown command/target logcat" when i try "buildozer logcat"

Comment: Seems this is a small error in the doc, it should be `buildozer android logcat`.

Comment: I've fixed it, and the website should update shortly.

Comment: I'm a kivy developer with push access to the website, but just one of several core developers, and I've been around a relatively short time in the context of the project :)

Comment: Logcat simply prints a continuous log of everything the device is doing. You should run it while you start the application, and see what it says when it crashes. You can see kivy messages only with `buildozer android logcat | grep python`.

Comment: Oh, I will try it again. Sorry for being so ignorant, I'm new to this stuff.

Comment: Here is the logcat information(http://pastebin.com/9BTEjrF7). If this is incorrect please let me know how to do it correctly.

Comment: I think it does arise from a now-fixed bug in kivy, as I guessed originally. Try replacing `kivy` with `kivy==master` in the buildozer.spec requirements.

Comment: Ok, now it does not crash, but where is the PNG saved?

Comment: In the current directory of your app, so somewhere in /data/data on android

Comment: They are not in android/data

Comment: Is there a possible way for me to set where the PNG is saved?

Comment: Yes, just print the current path and read the answer in the logcat stream. You can do this kind of thing with python's `os` module amongst others. You probably also want to save somewhere more easily accessible, such as in kivy.user_data_dir which will be in your external storage dir on android.

Comment: I am sorry for ariving late at the scene, but I have the exact same problem, i have an app that have 2 problems, firstly when I save the image using screenshot() it stores the image at data/data/#myfilenamedir#/files wich is kind of weird, and i cant get it to save it elsewhere, neither can i browse my way to it, i cant find data/data, secondly, the app's touching alignment is wrong, it semulates that i actuely press the screen 1.5 inches lower on the screen than i actualy did, this is rather erritating, id realy apreciate any help, thanks!, ps: buildozer, android lollipop, python2.7

Comment: /data/data is the internal data directory, you can't access that as a normal directory without root. Use the external storage path (something like /storage/emulated/0 without an sdcard, probably, you can look it up or use pyjnius to query the system for it) to finda  path you can browse to normally.

Comment: sorry, but how would one send the image to some other folder without root acces?

Comment: Your app automatically has write access to a certain folder in the external data dir, and kivy apps automaticaly request an extra write permission in this directory so you can use any folder there anyway.